# Symfony enter route only if user agent matches condition?

Tags: php, symfony

**The problem**

I have a web-server that generates an index page that runs Angular, which uses API calls to display data.

I have meta tags which are being set by Angular API calls too.

Now if I will post my website on Facebook, the tags will not be initialized because Facebook scrawler does not support Javascript.

**Solution**
Detect Facebook user-agent server-sided, and dedicate specific routes that will use a controller action that returns an index page already initialized with that meta data that facebook needs, using the API calls server sided.

I have tried using the `condition` option that I [read here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html) in Symfony router but I am getting the following error:

```
Resources/config/routing.yml"
   contains unsupported keys for "bot_facebook_post": "condition"
```

And that's how my route looks in yml:

```
bot_facebook_post:
    pattern: /locations/{location}
    condition: "request.headers.get('User-Agent') matches 'facebookexternalhit/1.1'"
    defaults: {
        _controller: Main:bot, slug: ""
    }
```

Comment: Cant edit the question, but the error keys for "bot_facebook_post"

Comment: Seems like the place I read about condition is symfony 4, but I am using Symfony 2

Comment: Which version of symfony 2?

Comment: It says 2.3.21-DEV in the kernel

Comment: Considering documentation, condition is supported since 2.7

Comment: @Cid Is there a way to do such thing in this version?

Comment: I'd say use that condition inside controller. Or even better, migrate to a maintained version of Symfony